# Preventing GitPython from asking for credentials when trying to clone a non-existent remote repo

Tags: python, gitpython

In the program fragment below, I clone an existing repo from a remote location and it works correctly.

Then I try to clone a non-existent repo, and this time the call to `git.Repo.clone_from()` requests a name and a password from the keyboard.

Blocking while waiting for keyboard input is highly undesirable in my application, and so if the repo doesn't exist, I want the call to `git.Repo.clone_from()` to throw an exception instead.

Is there any way to cause that to happen, or to somehow detect whether or not there exists a git repo at an existing URL before I even try to clone it?

```
import git, shutil

DIRECTORY = '/tmp/clone'


def clone(url):
    print(url)
    shutil.rmtree(DIRECTORY, ignore_errors=True)
    git.Repo.clone_from(url=url, to_path=DIRECTORY, b='master')


clone('https://github.com/ManiacalLabs/BiblioPixelAnimations.git/')
clone('https://github.com/ManiacalLabs/NONEXISTENT.git/')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting an empty username and password should do the trick

```
clone('https://:@github.com/ManiacalLabs/BiblioPixelAnimations.git/')
clone('https://:@github.com/ManiacalLabs/NONEXISTENT.git/')
```

Note there is `:@` before `github.com`.

Comment: I just tried it with my test program and it worked right the first time - A+++.